# Core Data data synchronise in background

Tags: ios, core-data, fetch, backend

I am working on an application which initially fetches some data from the backend service and store in the app sqlite using core data. The managed objects undergo many changes during the app usage. In a timely manner the data should be synchronised with the backend service.

I tried to use two managed object context, one for user interface interaction and one for synchronisation with backend so that I can merge the context. But the context used by the UI is not saved to the persistent storage every time and hence when i fetch using the second context there is mismatch in the managed objects.

Secondly I tried using the parent child context. Parent context for UI interaction and child for timely data synchronisation. But sometime I see the UI gets blocked forever. I have made sure that actions on the managed objects are executed in a block on respective managed object context.

My question is, how can I handle the new data received from the service and update the managed object without blocking the user interface.

Comment: Your general approach is correct. The problems you face are due to some mistake in implementation.

Comment: yes. We are analysing it. Thanks for your response

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a post that describes a few possible setups](http://floriankugler.com/2013/04/29/concurrent-core-data-stack-performance-shootout/). I'll summarize some of the main points and solutions.

Your second attempt failed because your UI (parent) context was still doing store I/O on the main thread, which is why it was blocking.

**Solution 1** - Keep your contexts separate like you tried first.

> Change propagation between the contexts is achieved by subscribing to the NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification and calling mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification: on the other context.

So you subscribe to the notification from the private service context; and then call -mergeChanges... on the UI context, which keeps them synchronized and is very fast.

**Solution 2** - make your UI context a child of a third Private Queue context.  In other words, your stack is *Persistent Store* <- *New Private Context* <- *UI (Main Queue) Context* <- *Private synchronization context*.  This moves your disk I/O to the background which should keep your UI responsive.  Note however, that now you also have to call save on the UI context and the new context to persist changes from the background; plus this approach is slower than Solution 1